# How to query and filter the minimum value in one column while keeping the other columns in SQL

Tags: sql, toad

How can I keep only the minimum value in one column while preserving the rest of the data in the other columns in SQL?  I'm trying to filter the field 'OrderID' to exhibit the lowest order# by CustomerID and Level.

Table:

```
Order# |CustomerID | Level
12345  | 200       | 3
12389  | 200       | 3
12590  | 200       | 3
12790  | 200       | 4
13091  | 200       | 5
15678  | 500       | 3
15788  | 500       | 4
16100  | 500       | 4
16990  | 500       | 5
17331  | 600       | 3
17660  | 600       | 4
17700  | 600       | 5
```

My goal is identify the when the CustomerID hit level 3,4,5 the first time based on their Order# by having a Result table below.

All other Order#'s after they hit the level are removed and a new column Level 3, Level 4, and Level 5 are created to indicate what was the order number that met those level thresholds.

Result

```
CustomerID | Level 3 | Level 4| Level 5
200        | 12345   | 12790  | 13091
500        | 15678   | 15788  | 16990
600        | 17331   | 17660  | 17700
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just suggest conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN OrderNo END) AS Level3,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Level = 4 THEN OrderNo END) AS Level4,
       MIN(CASE WHEN Level = 5 THEN OrderNo END) AS Level5
FROM t
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID;
```

Neither a subquery nor window functions are needed for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to handle using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, Level ORDER BY OrderNo) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    CustomerID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 3 AND rn = 1 THEN OrderNo END) AS Level3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 4 AND rn = 1 THEN OrderNo END) AS Level4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 5 AND rn = 1 THEN OrderNo END) AS Level5
FROM cte
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY CustomerID;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!   Today I learned about Row_Number() over Partition by....  Thank you!!